# Is a shul allowed to have stadium seating?

Tags: halacha, synagogue

Years ago, I attended [Lincoln Square Synagogue](https://www.lss.org/) when [Rabbi Riskin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Riskin) was Rav. It is the only shul that I know of that is built like a stadium, with the ark in the front of the shul (I.e. if one drew a diameter with one end being the shul entrance, then the other end had the ark.)

Seats were arranged in concentric rows with the shulchan (Torah readers platform) in the middle, and each row (circle) higher than the one inside of it. Like so:

[image]

What allows this shul arrangement? (*I assume if Rabbi Riskin allowed it, it's OK.*) Isn't there a rule that one must not daven from a "high  place"? Here, some people are higher than others? Secondly, isn't the entire congregation supposed to face in the same direction, i.e .towards the ark, but also in the same compass direction? In a circular shul, to face the ark, everyone must face in a different direction, so some people are facing each other.

Comment: Do you have a reason that this should not be permitted? In halacha there is no need to assume something isn't permitted without a reason to say this thing isn't muter.

Comment: In context it's clear that the prohibition from davening from a high place applies to somewhere where you'd be afraid of falling off and therefore unable to focus properly. In response to your point about facing the proper direction while davening, having benches not all facing the same direction is a very common design in synagogues. In my experience, people just turn the correct way when davening _shmoneh esrei_.

Comment: Is your concern where the ark and the shulchan were positioned or that congregants were seated above the shulchan? Lincoln Square Synagogue moved into a new facility in 2013 with a modern interpretation of the original stadium/ampitheatre  seating design. The only halakhic concern that was voiced concerning the seating arrangement in either building  was/is the appropriateness of the mekhitza. The new building includes sections that accommodates those who are more strict. Depending on where you are seated at LSS, people simply turn towards the ark while standing.

Comment: IIRC the Young Israel of Scarsdale had that.

Comment: The chazzan is supposed to be lower than everyone else. "HaYored Lofnei HaTevah..."

Comment: I don't know about a stadium seating, but I've been in several shuls in which the seats are arranged in a circle.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's not the case in a number of shuls. I won't, for now, address a common Conservative shul arrangement where not only is teh chazzan davening from the front bima facing the cong. (separate problem, here, perhaps), but in numerous Orth. shuls, esp. on Rosh Hashanna, most of the chazzan's davening occurs from the Torah shulchan which is on a bima that is higher than the congregation. Likewise, for Kabbalat Shabbat (unless Kabbalat Shabbat is not considered part of "tefilla", anyway.)

Comment: @DonielF I've seen that too. Actually, quite common in older shuls that have a downward slope going towards the front. By "stadium", I meant what you typically see in a baseball stadium which is not only tiered but round or oval.

Comment: @DanF Yep, sounds like you're describing my home shul, with the slope. Built in the '60s.

Comment: I've been in several Orthodox shuls where the women's section was a balcony.  If height were a problem, wouldn't that pose a problem for balconies?

Comment: @MonicaCellio That's an excellent question. The *ezrat nashim* concept, if I'm not mistaken, originated in the Bet Hamikdash. The story about SImchat Bet Hasho'eva the celebration during Succot, seems to confirm the idea that women were in a balcony. However, this was not a prayer occasion. I'm assuming that since women don't have the same obligation to pray, and, there's certainly no obligation to attend shul for services, the women's balcony may not pose any problem. It may be one, if men were in a balcony.

Comment: @DanF I'm not an expert, but it seems to me that *if* women's public prayer is valid at all then it has to follow the same rules as men's, and if it's not then we'd take steps to clarify its status (even if building balconies to grant access or whatever).  It would seem odd to me to say that we provide those balconies for prayer but prayer would be invalid if done there.  Anyway, not trying to start a discussion in comments (feel free to ping me in chat); I'm just suggesting a consideration for your question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It is something to consider. But, offhand, I think this should be a separate question. But you got me thinking, so thanks!

Comment: http://ph.yhb.org.il/02-03-04/

Comment: The Beth Jacob in Atlanta had a similar setup - https://static1.squarespace.com/static/538b5739e4b0f18802f0bcd3/t/53f9eda6e4b08bf8d1cf3a28/1408888242480/image.jpg?format=750w - (They are now doing renovations)

Comment: Thanks to the person who put in the pic. Offhand, this doesn't look like Lincoln Square - at least not the "old" version. I haven't been to the new one. But, where have all the people gone???